# Adding style to CommandItemSettings RadGrid button

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am trying to add a red asterisk after the 'AddNewRecordText' button with in RadGrid. Here is the code. The red asterisk should show after 'Add Award' text. Could you please let me know if there are any suggestions? Thank you.

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="99%" 
  runat="server" MasterTableView-AllowAutomaticInserts="true" GridLines="None" Skin="Default"
                ShowFooter="false" ShowStatusBar="false">
    <MasterTableView Width="100%" DataKeyNames="c_id" CommandItemDisplay="Top"
         CommandItemSettings-ShowAddNewRecordButton="true">
    <CommandItemSettings AddNewRecordText="Add Award *" ShowAddNewRecordButton="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RadGrid prerenders AddNewRecordText as a `<a>` element. and you cannot add different styles to one element.
To change that default behavior, you will have to use [CommandItemTemplate](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-commanditemtemplate.html).
[This demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/commanditem/defaultcs.aspx) should be a good start for you.

Another simple approach, is that you always can change any style on your page with jquery.
this should work for you (works for me, probably you will have to change ids):

```
$('a[id$="InitInsertButton"]') //this means: find all <a> elements that have id ending with "InitInsertButton"
   .first() //Get the first element to be sure.
   .append('<span style="color:red"> *</span>') //Add text inside a attribute.
```

You will have to add this code on [document.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).
Here's a small jsfiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/rXhnM/

Answer (score 0):

So I'm late to the party again, but you can get a reference to that control on the server side:

```
protected void HandleGridItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
 if(e.Item is GridCommandItem)
 {
  var button = e.Item.FindControl("SaveChangesIcon") as Button;
  var link = e.Item.FindControl("SaveChangesButton") as LinkButton;
  button.Text += "<span class='red'>*</span>";
 }
}
```

I needed to add a bit of javascript to run when clicked so this is how I managed to pull it off. I imagine adding * and appending to the text property yield the result you're looking for. We're on the 2016 version of the Telerik control set.